# R - Setting Value Based on Matching to Column Name

Tags: r

Afternoon clever people.

I have a decent sized data set (>800k rows) and as an example I have pulled out a tiny sample of 20 columns by 2 rows.  At the outset only the "Topics" column is populated with a vector, all other columns are set to FALSE.

This will recreate the data as it sits currently...

```
  Topics <- c("E11,E31,E313,ECAT" , "E1,E20") 
  E1     <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  E11    <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  E20    <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  E30    <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  E31    <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  E100   <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  E300   <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  E313   <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  ECAT   <- c(FALSE, FALSE)
  df     <- data.frame(Topics,E1,E11,E20,E30,E31,E100,E300,E313,ECAT)
```

Which will give something like...

```
Topics              E1    E11   E20   E30   E31   E100  E300  E313  ECAT
E11,E31,E313,ECAT   FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
E1,E20              FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I want to set the relevant row,column to TRUE where there is a match for each of the items in the topic vector. So it should look something like...

```
Topics              E1    E11   E20   E30   E31   E100  E300  E313  ECAT
E11,E31,E313,ECAT   FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE TRUE
E1,E20              TRUE  FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So far I have failed UTTERLY to work this one out but I suspect it is something like:

- split the topic into a vector using `strsplit`
- for each item in vector try to match to `names(df)`
- when matched set row,column == TRUE

BUT I have tried all sorts and cannot fathom the logic.  Can anyone break this down for me please?

Comment: In the expected result, `E313` should be `TRUE` instead of `E300`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df[-1] <-  t(vapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Topics), ','),
                 function(x) names(df)[-1] %in% x, logical(ncol(df)-1)))
df
#             Topics    E1   E11   E20   E30   E31  E100  E300  E313  ECAT
#1 E11,E31,E313,ECAT FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#2            E1,E20  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Or

```
 df[-1] <- t(vapply(strsplit(as.character(df$Topics), ","), function(x)
         !!table(factor(x, levels=names(df)[-1])), logical(ncol(df)-1)))
```

Comment: Epic.   So I spend a whole day and probably put down 50 - 60 lines of code trying to get this to work..   You do it in ONE!   Outstanding and just goes to show how much further I have to go with R.  Cheers.

Comment: @BarneyC Glad to help you.  It is only based on experience.

Comment: May I ask what would I change if there was another column before "Topic" ?      I guess I'm asking what each of the -1 indexes means and to what would I set them.  Cheers

Comment: @BarneyC Here I used `-1` for selecting all the columns except the 1st column.  Here, it is `Topics`.  Suppose, you have another column before `Topic`, then the index should be `df[-c(1,2)]` and change `names(df)[-(1:2)]` and `logical(ncol(df)-2)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's almost a step-by-step approach to the logic you describe:

```
## make note of the column names
Colnames <- names(df[-1])

## Create an empty FALSE matrix to modify later
Mat <- matrix(FALSE, nrow = nrow(df), 
              ncol = length(Colnames), 
              dimnames = list(NULL, Colnames))

## Use strsplit to split the "Topics" column
L <- strsplit(as.character(df[[1]]), ",", fixed = TRUE)

## Figure out which values match with which columns
## I'm using matrix indexing here to set those values to TRUE
Mat[cbind(rep(seq_along(L), vapply(L, length, 1L)),
          match(unlist(L), Colnames))] <- TRUE

## Replacement in the original dataset
df[-1] <- Mat
df
#              Topics    E1   E11   E20   E30   E31  E100  E300  E313  ECAT
# 1 E11,E31,E313,ECAT FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 2            E1,E20  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

---

If you were just starting with the "Topics" column, here are a few variations you can consider:

1. `mtabulate` from "qdapTools"

   ```
   > library(qdapTools)
   > mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df$Topics), ",", TRUE))
     E1 E11 E20 E31 E313 ECAT
   1  0   1   0   1    1    1
   2  1   0   1   0    0    0
   ```
2. `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package

   ```
   library(splitstackshape)
   cSplit_e(df[1], "Topics", ",", type = "character", fill = 0)
   #              Topics Topics_E1 Topics_E11 Topics_E20 Topics_E31 Topics_E313 Topics_ECAT
   # 1 E11,E31,E313,ECAT         0          1          0          1           1           1
   # 2            E1,E20         1          0          1          0           0           0
   ```

Both would require a little bit of extra work to make sure that all of the columns you expect to have are included (and to convert from 1 and 0 to `TRUE` and `FALSE`).

Comment: That walkthrough is great and is far more in line with how I was thinking it could be approached.  Thanks for that.