# R - Combining Columns to String Based on Logical Match

Tags: r

In a previous question ([Setting Value Based on Matching Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815750/r-setting-value-based-on-matching-to-column-name)) I was trying to take a string, split it into elements and create a column per element with a logical statement.  This was answered brilliantly.

But after a couple of months work on things I now need something on the lines of an inverse.

Given...

```
df     <- data.frame(E1=FALSE,E11=TRUE,E20=FALSE,E30=FALSE,E31=TRUE,E100=FALSE,E300=FALSE,E313=TRUE,ECAT=TRUE)
```

I need to produce a string containing all the column names that have a `TRUE` match - which would hopefully yield something like...

```
> df[1,]
     E1    E11   E20   E30   E31   E100  E300  E313  ECAT  Topics
  1  FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE TRUE  TRUE  E11,E31,E313,ECAT
```

In reality I have 3,270 rows and there are actually 102 topics so really I need something that will for each row provide a concatenation of those `TRUE` topic codes.

My attempts have yielded nothing working, who will volunteer up an answer OR a link to duplicate question/answer (as they probably exist - it is an R question after all)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
df$Topics <- apply(df, 1, function(x) toString(names(x)[x]))
```

Comment: Quick question - how does this check know to only use the `TRUE` answers without an `if`?

Comment: @BarneyC `TRUE/FALSE` is logical index, so subsetting by that, gives only the names corresponding to the TRUE values.  Check `(1:3)[c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)]`   BTW, `toString` is a wrapper for `paste(., collapse=", ")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apply` to do this.

```
df$Topics = apply(df,1,function(x) paste0(colnames(df)[x],collapse=','))
```

Comment: LOL that was rather similar to my last (failed) attempt.  Big difference is I had `apply(df,2,function...` and `paste(names(df[x])...`