# Concatenate column names in data.table based on conditions

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lapply

This is what my data.table looks like. The rightmost column `PASTE` is my desired column.

```
library(data.table) 

    dt <- fread('
    A      B     C      PASTE
    TRUE  FALSE TRUE    A,C   
    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE    A;B;C
    FALSE TRUE  FALSE   B
    FALSE FALSE FALSE   
    ')
```

I am trying to create the column `PASTE` by concatenating all the column names **as long as the value in that row for that column is TRUE.**

This is my attempt:

```
dt[,PASTE:= if(dt[,c(1:3),with=FALSE] == TRUE, paste(names(dt), sep= ";"),"")]
```

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102847/r-combining-columns-to-string-based-on-logical-match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can grouo by the rows, `unlist` the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`), subset the names of the dataset, `paste` the elements together and assign (`:=`) to 'newCol'

```
nm1 <- names(dt)[-4]
dt[, newCol := toString(nm1[unlist(.SD)]) ,by = 1:nrow(dt),.SDcols = nm1]
```

---

Or another option is `melt` to 'long' format and then do a join

```
dt[melt(dt[, n := seq_len(.N)], id.var = c("n", "PASTE"))[,
               toString(variable[value]), n], on = "n"]
```